# Rails - periodically update certain tags without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, prototypejs

I am creating a statusboard that will show specific details of several servers and need help with updating the view.

**Background:** 
I have the main setup created where I have the following:

- A MySQL database that keeps hold of the server information called servers
- Using bootstrap to show the content
- A ruby script to grab each servers information and updating the database (method called update_all_servers in the application.rb file)
- Cronjob that runs the ruby script every minute

**What I need help with:** 
Basically, I need help with the javascript part of my rails app. I am not too sure exactly how too update individual attributes of each server in the table I have. What I am looking for is that the javascript/ajax code will periodically grab the updated values from the database every 30 seconds and update the view without refreshing the page.

In my index.html, you can see that I have placed an id="comments" for the server.rhel_version attribute. I was thinking I could use the $(#comments). to update it. Either in the application.js file or some other efficient/logical method.

Below is all my source code. If you guys could guide me on the approach I should take and possibly provide some sample code, I would really appreciate it!

**/views/servers/index.html.erb**

```
<%- model_class = Server.new.class -%>
<div class="page-header">
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize %></h1>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
 <!--     <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:id) %></th> -->
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:hostname) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:port) %></th>
  <!--    <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:username) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:password) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:ssh_username) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:ssh_password) %></th> 
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:source_branch) %></th> -->
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:source_revision) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:release) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:rhel_version) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:gpu_type) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:total_users) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:current_users) %></th>
      <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
      <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @servers.each do |server| %>
      <tr>
  <!--      <td><%= link_to server.id, server_path(server) %></td> -->
        <td><%= server.hostname %></td>
        <td><%= server.port %></td>
   <!--     <td><%= server.username %></td>
        <td><%= server.password %></td>
        <td><%= server.ssh_username %></td>
        <td><%= server.ssh_password %></td>
        <td><%= server.source_branch %></td> -->
        <td><%= server.source_revision %></td>
        <td><%= server.release %></td>
        <td id="comments"><%= server.rhel_version %></td>
        <td><%= server.gpu_type %></td>
        <td><%= server.total_users %></td>
        <td><%= server.current_users %></td>
        <td><%=l server.created_at %></td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_server_path(server), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      server_path(server),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
                      :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_server_path,
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

**/controllers/servers_controller.rb**

```
class ServersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /servers
  # GET /servers.json
  def index
    @servers = Server.all

    update_all_servers

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @servers }
    end
  end

  # GET /servers/1
  # GET /servers/1.json
  def show
    @server = Server.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @server }
    end
  end

  # GET /servers/new
  # GET /servers/new.json
  def new
    @server = Server.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @server }
    end
  end

  # GET /servers/1/edit
  def edit
    @server = Server.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /servers
  # POST /servers.json
  def create
    @server = Server.new(params[:server])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @server.save
        format.html { redirect_to @server, notice: 'Server was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @server, status: :created, location: @server }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @server.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /servers/1
  # PUT /servers/1.json
  def update
    @server = Server.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @server.update_attributes(params[:server])
        format.html { redirect_to @server, notice: 'Server was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @server.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /servers/1
  # DELETE /servers/1.json
  def destroy
    @server = Server.find(params[:id])
    @server.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to servers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

**/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**Screenshot of view:** 
[image: statusboard view]

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of these with [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and if you search you can easily find related question/answers eg [How to fire AJAX request Periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically)

Comment: I guess I should also add, how would one go about getting the server values from the database through javascript, such as server.hostname, server.username, etc..?