# In rails 3.2 app, what is the best way to update a page when a background job is complete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails 3.2 app has a report page that frequently takes 90+ seconds to render, so I run the report-builder as a delayed_job task then display a "wait a minute" view (with a refresh button) until the content is ready (there is a `content_ready` flag used in the view to display either the "wait message" or the report, as appropriate). In my prototype, the user has to refresh the page manually until the `content_ready` is set (and then the report view is rendered).

I'd like to have the page refresh automatically when `content_ready` is true.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this, given it's a rarely-hit page and thus an inefficient method, such as telling the user's browser to poll the server (or redraw the whole page) every 10 seconds, is just fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup either a meta-refresh on the page or an ajax updater (if using jquery, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052661/403664)) that checks a specific controller action that tells you whether the job is completed, or that the file exists in the location expected.

Or, and assuming you're using the delayed_job gem, check out the hooks that are provided as part of the job queuing execution. There is documentation on the [gem's GH page](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).

Comment: An important caveat re the "meta-refresh" approach is Firefox disables the meta refresh by default. (We use the browser gem to add a manual refresh message and button for our Firefox users who are increasingly in the minority thank goodness.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the following strategy:

- After creating the delayed job, pass the id of the job back to the browser immediately.
- Expose an endpoint on your site that will return the status of the job.
- Use jQuery + setTimeout or setInterval to hit the endpoint.
- When the job is done, redirect the user to the appropriate page.

It's a pretty simple strategy, but it works.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going the meta-refresh route but your answer was helpful as well.