# How can I add a background thread in form load function for notification in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I want to receive notification from database when table is updated but I need a background thread which call after 1 mint and check database table and show me notification. How can I implement a background thread? I have implemented a thread but when I use while(true) in it, my form is not loaded keep on processing.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Function1));
    t1.IsBackground = true;
    t1.Start();
}

private void Function1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        count++;                
        Label1.Text = "Function" + count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use background `thread` on asp.net page. It works on `http` stateless protocol and the page object is not available after the response it sent. You can only send one response against one request. You can use [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) , [asp.net ajax library timer control](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/tutorials/IntroToTimerControl.aspx) or [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) to fetch data from server periodically.

This **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically)** explains how you can fetch data from server using jQuery ajax. This is also very good [tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) to get the data from server using web methods. The example from this tutorial is given below.

**Code behind**

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I have link to the post that can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically

Comment: This code refresh my whole page i just wana refresh my label through timer_tick is it possible.....?

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between server-side and client-side code.

For example, your request would require a framework such as SignalR to push a real-time notification to a client.

The easier method is to use Javascript to poll a page of your choice.. for example (jQuery, obviously):

```
// I'm not a huge jQuery person so theres probably a jQuery way to do this
setInterval(function() { 
    $.get('/yourPage.aspx', function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            alert(response.message);
        }
    });
}, 5000); // poll a page every 5 seconds.
```

Then your C# page at `/yourPage.aspx` can check the database and return a Json object with the properties I've mentioned above.

You need to read up on the difference between Client Side and Server Side.. and how they interact in a stateless protocol such as HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can do async tasks in ASP.NET if you are using the 4.5 framework:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx