# automate an ajax call in view

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an a link tied to a refresh icon that calls a backend function to reload a section of the page and grab new results to display to the client end.

the function itself works just fine.  I now want to automate it in JavaScript to fire off like every 30 seconds.

This is the current link I have:

```
<a data-ajax="post" data-ajax-callback="PagingCallBack" data-ajax-start="PagingStart" href="@Url.RouteUrl("Engagement", new { controller = "Campaign", action = "PageRefresh", queryID = Model.QueryID, campaignID = Model.CampaignID })" title="Refresh Row">
<img class="rowGrabber" src="/images/actions/refresh.png" height="20" width="20" alt="Refresh Row" title="Refresh Row" />
</a>
```

how would i take that and set it into a javascript function and call it every 30 seconds or so.

I looked at this response here and it's similar to what I'm looking for I just don't know the call syntax to make it work properly.
[How to fire AJAX request Periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a way to identify your anchor tag (in this example add class="refresh-link" to you a tag  or use your own class or id then simply use something like the following:

which will trigger the link every 30 seconds

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $(".refresh-link").trigger('click');
}, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
   //Your Ajax request or call your function here
   }, 30000); //30000 is the number of milliseconds
```