# AJAX jQuery refresh div every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I got this code from a website which I have modified to my needs:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="links">

</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var timeout = setTimeout(reloadChat, 5000);

function reloadChat () {
$('#links').load('test.php #links',function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
        timeout = setTimeout(reloadChat, 5000);
});
}
</script>
```

In test.php:

```
<?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

So I want test.php to be called every 5 seconds in links div. How can I do this right?

Comment: Are you including the jquery library

Comment: Yes I got <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> in head above

Comment: you are using an old version ogf jquery , try the latest version <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: AJAX polling is an anti-pattern which should be avoided at all costs. It's not a scalable solution and will cause server-side performance problems with minimal concurrent load. A better solution when you need to keep client/server side data in close sync is to use the observer pattern instead. In this case, websockets.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this out.

```
function loadlink(){
    $('#links').load('test.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Updated my answer with $(this).unwrap();   In this you wont need the timeout = setTimeout(reloadChat, 5000);

Comment: It's not working, is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js the right library?

Comment: Oh wait it's working, thanks :) but "test" comes 5 seconds after pageload, is the way to do it instant onload and then refresh every 5 sec?

Comment: Great now it's perfect :) Thanks

Comment: TIL `unwrap()` is a thing. Thank lord.

Comment: Great stuff! But what about counting the page loads. Setting a counter variable that increments every 5 seconds (or every second)?

Comment: But this will hit the server every 5 seconds. so my server will become busy unnecessary for every 5 sec

Comment: @rupesh can you please tell some other way to fetch fresh data from server without sending request to server? If the requirement is to refresh after every 5 seconds. Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

Try using `setInterval` and include `jquery library` and just try removing `unwrap()`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var timeout = setInterval(reloadChat, 5000);    
function reloadChat () {

     $('#links').load('test.php');
}
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

you are using a jquery old version so include the latest jquery version

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: this script works but the first seconds there is no content in the div. can the content also load on page load ?

Answer (score 5):

Try to not use `setInterval`.
 You can resend request to server after successful response with timeout.
jQuery:

`sendRequest(); //call function`

```
function sendRequest(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        success: 
        function(result){
            $('#links').text(result); //insert text of test.php into your div
            setTimeout(function(){
                sendRequest(); //this will send request again and again;
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: could you please explain why not setInterval?

Comment: this answer led to another answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052661/3842368 which suggests moving it from 'success' to 'complete'. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this one.

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

you java script code should be like that.

```
setInterval(function(){
      $('#test').load('test.php');
 },5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#tableHolder').load('getTable.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 5000);
    });
}
</script>
```