# Getting an AJAX call to reload a div every x minutes

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm new to Javascript and AJAX so please excuse my newb question.  I have an AJAX call (that is working) and I'd like to have it refresh the contents of a div every 5 minutes (I'm not using jquery). This is how I'm calling the AJAX function in the `<head></head>` of my html page:

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
        setInterval(ajaxCall(), 300000);
    </script>
```

The initial page load populates the div, but the content of the div doesn't refresh after 5 minutes.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Call your div id.
Or take a look here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446628/ajax-jquery-refresh-div-every-5-seconds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
setInterval(ajaxCall, 300000);
```

To pass an argument:

```
setInterval(function(){ ajaxCall(someCoolValue); }, 300000);
```

Notice the lack of parentheses in `ajaxCall`. You want to pass the function itself, not call the function. [More examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Comment: Thanks Andy. I need to pass an argument to to the ajaxCall. I should have specified that when I posted the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your `ajaxCall`.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    setInterval(function(){ ajaxCall(); }, 300000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="links">

</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var timeout = setTimeout(reloadChat, 300000);

function reloadChat () {
$('#links').load('test.php #links',function () {
        $(this).unwrap();
        timeout = setTimeout(reloadChat, 300000);
});
}
</script>
```

Also you are calling it wrong correct syntax would be ,

```
setInterval(ajaxCall, 300000);
```

Hope it helps :D