# Auto Refresh IFrame HTML

Tags: html, iframe, automation, refresh, element

How do I auto Refresh a Iframe every 3 Seconds with out it refreshing the entire page. I use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">` but it shows the entire page refresh and puts you to the top of the page each time it does. My Iframe is pointed at a text file to read live messages I put in. Is there even a way to do this with out it refreshing the entire page, just the element. I am a HTML beginner so explain thoroughly please. I google alot and tried many things and so far nothing works and I try in many browser.

My code So Far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />



<title>Chat</title>

<style>

body{
margin: 0px;
}

h1{
font-family: arial;
font-size: 100%;
}
iframe{
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
}

div.top{
background-color: rgba(2, 109, 8, 0.83);
height: 30px;
width: 100%;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div class="top">
<img src="favicon.png" alt="favicon"  height="31" width="31" >
<h1>Chat</h1>
</div>




<iframe src="text.txt" name="iframe_a"> />



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446628/ajax-jquery-refresh-div-every-5-seconds).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/86428/2517622

Comment: Still No Help. Does same thing

Answer (score 4):

You have problems with your html tags.
(the "iframe" tag is malformed)

Here you have your code fixed and your answer ready to run:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Chat</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 100%;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 900px;
            height: 500px;
        }
        div.top {
            background-color: rgba(2, 109, 8, 0.83);
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <img src="favicon.png" alt="favicon" height="31" width="31">
        <h1>Chat</h1>
    </div>

    <iframe id="iframe" src="text.txt"></iframe>

    <script>
        window.setInterval(function() {
            reloadIFrame()
        }, 3000);

        function reloadIFrame() {
            console.log('reloading..');
            document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
    <script>
        function refreshIFrame() {
            var x = document.getElementById("*Your_iframe_id*");
            x.contentWindow.location.reload();
            var t = setTimeout(refreshIFrame, 3000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="refreshIFrame()">... 
    <iframe id="*Your_iframe_id*" src= ...></iframe>...
</body>
```

this solution worked for me, I discovered that the 'refreshIFrame()' function was entered as a parameter without the braces () in the following line: " *var t = setTimeout(**refreshIFrame**, 3000);* ". Just substitute the relevant values and you are good to go.

Answer (score -1):

You could accomplish what you need by simply using a few lines of Javascript.

```
 <script>
 window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 3000);

 function reloadIFrame() {
  document.frames["frameNameHere"].location.reload();
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Doesn't Work in Firefox or Chrome or IE.

Comment: I Put it in and Nothing Happens.

Comment: Did you replace it with your frame name?

Comment: I just get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'frameNameHere')`.  I don't think `document` even has a `frames` property.  Did you test this code?  Can you provide a complete, working example?