# How to update specific div using JQuery AJAX after regular time intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, marko

I want to update specific `div` - not full html page .When i run the following code it works fine but it reloads whole html. Moreover, I'm  using different layouts e.g i have `header`, `layout`, `footer` in different file.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout( function(){  
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3002/jrt/?jId=$data.jacket.id',
      method: "GET",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        //$("#gt").append(data);
        $( '#gt' ).html( data );
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error ' + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
      }
    })
  },10000);
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446628/ajax-jquery-refresh-div-every-5-seconds. Search before asking questions

Comment: You're updating a specific element: `$('#gt').html(data);`  If you want to update a different element, change the selector to identify that element instead.

Comment: Show us your HTML too.. is `html` has the id `gt`? If not, who the element `#gt`?

Comment: yes   its like  <section id='gt'> </section

Comment: But this section is the root element? I mean, is he wrap the whole page or part of it? If it's wrap only, part it shouldn't refresh the whole page. Maybe it something else.

Comment: Also, why are you including the domain (e.g. localhost) in the url? You know that when you will publish it, you will have to change this? It will be better if you call the relative path (without the domain)

Comment: am using markojs which uses templates .  and  am including files  like

Comment: am using markojs which uses templates . and am including files like
<layout-use template="./shared/home/layout.marko">
<layout-put into="body">
<section id="gt"></section>

</layout-put>
</layout-use>

Comment: So `#gt` is the app wrapper. If you want to change more specific section, try to change the selector..

Answer (score 1):

assuming the data returned is html you can select something in it by doing `$(data).find('your-selector')` to edit your example:

```
[...]
success: function(data) {
   $( '#gt .something-inside' ).html( $(data).find('.something-inside') );
},
[...]
```

Comment: `assuming the date returned is html` - why are you assuming this? Read the comments..

Comment: @moshFeu because you said the whole HTML reloads, so i assumed it reloads with other HTML you get form the request. anyway then you just have to do  `$( '#gt .something-inside' ).html( data );`

Comment: Apparently you are kind of right. Is not the `html` element but it's the root element of the application..