# How to refresh a div every X seconds which reads data from file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I need to refresh a div every few seconds on my below `index.php` page.

```
<?php

session_start();

if (! check_write()) {
    redirect('testlogin.php');
    return;
}

if (file_exists('lmt.json')) {
    $lmt = json_decode(file_get_contents("lmt.json"), true);
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Website Title</h1> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </div>
    <div>
        <p>Welcome back,
            <?= $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- How can I refresh below div every x seconds? -->
    <div>
        <?php if (isset($lmt)) { ?>
            <p>Last modified by <?= $lmt['fname']; ?> at <?= $lmt['ts']; ?></p>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="field1" />
        <input type="text" name="field2" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data"> </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post({
                url: 'save.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
            }).done(response => {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if(response.message) {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the div I want to refresh every X seconds. As of now it just gets the value from `$lmt` variable and show it to the user but I want to refresh that div every X seconds by reading from `lmt.json` file and then show `fname` and `ts` variable.

```
<!-- How can I refresh below div every x seconds? -->
<div>
    <?php if (isset($lmt)) { ?>
        <p>Last modified by <?= $lmt['fname']; ?> at <?= $lmt['ts']; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AJAX jQuery refresh div every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446628/ajax-jquery-refresh-div-every-5-seconds)

Comment: I think you're looking for JavaScripts setInterval

Comment: I saw the link but my confusion is OP is calling `test.php` every 5 seconds in his div. In my cases I want to read file every X seconds in the div so that's where I am confuse. I noticed an answer where we are doing like this `$('#links').load('test.php',function () {`. And thats where i am confuse seeing `test.php` since in my case I need to read file every X seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write two seperate files `index.php` (It contains the div that you want to refresh) and `filehandle.php`(file contents that you should recieve).

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (! check_write()) {
    redirect('testlogin.php');
    return;
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Website Title</h1> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </div>
    <div>
        <p>Welcome back,
            <?= $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- How can I refresh below div every x seconds? -->
    <div class="update_content"></div>

    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="field1" />
        <input type="text" name="field2" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data"> </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var update_time = 1000;
    $.get('filehandle.php', function (data, status){
        $('.update_content').html(data);
    });
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('filehandle.php', function (data, status){
            $('.update_content').html(data);
        });
    }, update_time);

    $(function() {
        $('form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.post({
                url: 'save.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
            }).done(response => {
                response = JSON.parse(response);
                if(response.message) {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**filehandle.php**

```
<?php

if (file_exists('lmt.json')) {
    $lmt = json_decode(file_get_contents("lmt.json"), true);
}

if (isset($lmt)) {
    echo "<p>Last modified by ".$lmt['fname']." at ".$lmt['ts']."</p>";
}

?>
```

change the value of `update_time` value in `index.php` to your desired value (it refers to update every `update_time` seconds).

> Note: update_time = 1000 -> 1sec, 2000 -> 2sec, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a quick way to get this done and over with I would implore you to check on w3schools.com. Here's an interesting look into what you might want from your site. It's an insight on the setTimeout() and setInterval() function from vanilla JS. Happy coding!

[JS Timing](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)