# How to get data from database on system time at 15 minute interval?

Tags: java, javascript, mysql, jsp

I have Date_time field with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format in my database. I had stored 8 days data in my database. Now i want data at every 15 minute. what is the solution for it? please help me...

I have Date_time field with yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format in my database. I had stored 8 days data in my database. Now i want data at every 15 minute. what is the solution for it? please help me...

```
my code is:

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Fetching data from the database</title>

</head>
<body>
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Inv_id</th>
            <th>Inv_phase1_V</th>
            <th>Inv_phase1_A</th>
            <th>Inv_phase1_kW</th>
        </tr>
            <%
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solar";
                String username="root";
                String password="root";
                Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
                String query="select Inv_id,Inv_phase1_V,Inv_phase1_A,Inv_phase1_kW from inverter_detail";
                Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    String Inverter_id = rs.getString("Inv_id");
                    Double voltage = rs.getDouble("Inv_phase1_V");
                    Double ampere = rs.getDouble("Inv_phase1_A");
                    Double kiloWatt = rs.getDouble("Inv_phase1_kW");
                %>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cotainer"><%=Inverter_id%></td>
                        <td><%=voltage%></td>
                        <td><%=ampere%></td>
                        <td><%=kiloWatt%></td>
                    </tr>
                <%
                }
                %>
                <%
                    rs.close();
                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

now i want this value at every 15 minute interval. What can i do??? I have no more idea about javascript n jquery.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far - in code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please post some of your existing code. A similar question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically

Comment: Please post your question just once...

Answer (score 1):

Use this function i think it may help you

```
setInterval(function() {

  // place your code here

}, 15 * 60 * 1000); // for 15 mins
```

Comment: oops sorry.....then set as 15*1000*60

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Javascript to fetch these data? If your answer is yes, you may try use `window.setInterval(code, delay);`. This function executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

For instance:

```js
var time = 2000, //  Number of milliseconds
    message = "Requesting data...<br>", // Message (Dont worty about this.)
    container = $(".container");


setInterval(function() {

  container.append(message);

}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Just set the time for 15 minutes (900000 ms) and your method will make the request from server. This is a simple way that can help you.

Good luck!

WindowTimers.setInterval() - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval