# Preventing fade-out of any mouse-over div when a ajax get still update of that mouse-over element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have right side update box which display all new post and like of user followers . And when user mouse-over any one update, a another floating box display full post of that update (like facebook).

Update box get all update after 5000 ms interval.

I used this below script to display floating box. But my problem is when update box get new update then the floating box goes fade-out. That means the floating box only display for 5 second.

I want whatever does happen on update box, floating box will not be fade-out until user want.

I use share hosting, so all update create by Ajax GET with 5000ms interval.

[image]

my floating box script:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.upbox', function () {
var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('','');
$("#menu").fadeIn("slow");
    $('.loader2').show();
    $.get("uphover.php?id="+id, function(data) {
    $('#menu').empty().html(data);
    $('.loader2').hide();
 });
});
```

Comment: please post a JsFiddle ?

Comment: Did you try to use AJAX CALL instead of AJAX GET? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically Maybe you could control it better than GET.

Comment: @Frebin I can't make any fiddle. here I tried http://jsfiddle.net/5areLpj0/

Comment: @JuaRoAl I read this page nut can't understand how to do it Or how can it  solved this problem. thank you.