# Ajax call not firing periodically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to write an ajax call which fires in every 5 seconds. I can write an ajax call as below. But I cant make it periodically. Please help me.

```
var set_delay = 5000,
click = function () {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        alert("");
    })
    .always(function () {
        // ...
    });
};
click();
```

Comment: check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically) out, you should try to google before posting questions here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code :

```js
var set_delay = 5000,
click = function () {
    $.ajax({
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        alert("");
    })
    .always(function () {
        setTimeout(click, set_delay);
    });
};
click();
```