# Live changes on site

Tags: javascript, php, reload

I am trying to make a php file in which I will send data from database and through them i will show 0 or 1. In my example I have a table with two user_ids and a parameter `in` which takes the value 0 or 1. From **test.php** I fill a form by giving the user_id and I submit it. When I submit it for this user the parameter `in` becomes 0 if it was 1 and vise versa. In **next.php** I use `<iframe src="show.php">` and in **show.php** I show the `user_id` and `in`. What I want is when I submit a user_id, immediately to see the changes in **show.php**. What I did is to refresh the page all the time but it was too disturbing. Can you suggest something else? Here is some code.

**test.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'include_php/db.php';
global $dbcnx;
?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="id"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $res = mysqli_query($dbcnx, "select * from people where uid = ".$id.";");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    if($row['in'] == 0) $up = mysqli_query($dbcnx, "UPDATE `people` SET `in`=1 WHERE uid=".$id.";");
    else $up = mysqli_query($dbcnx, "UPDATE `people` SET `in`=0 WHERE uid=".$id.";");
}
```

**show.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'include_php/db.php';
global $dbcnx;

$res = mysqli_query($dbcnx, "select * from people");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo $row['uid']." ".$row['in']."<br/>";
}

print "<script>window.location.replace('show.php');</script>"; //here is the disturbing refresh
```

**next.php**

```
<iframe src="show.php">
```

Comment: Use a javascript library like Jquery to make Ajax request instead refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is live updates without hard refreshing your page. You can achieve this by using **AJAX** requests, or by using **websockets**.

With an ajax request, you could easily set a timeout function to refresh your iframe every x-seconds/minutes.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically) gives a good description on how to give it a go.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will upvote and accept your answer in a few days, because i stopped working for today and WEEKEND IS COMING!!