# How to call an ajax function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax and JavaScript.
What am trying to do is to call an ajax function several times to fetch certain data from a resource and then "push" all of the data into an array so that I can use it later on in the code. Here is my code.

```
var arr = [];
var users = ["brunofin", "comster404", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + users[i],
        success: function(data) {
            arr.push(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            arr.push("blank");
        },
        complete: function() {
            if (i == users.length) {
                console.log(arr); //This seem to print even when the condition isn't true
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem with the code is that, it prints to the console even when `i` isn't equal to `users.length`

My question is; how do I make certain that it waits until `i == users.length` is true before it prints to the console?
Please keep in mind that I still desire the process to be asynchronous.

Comment: AJAX is Asynchronous( as per your code though) i.e., you'll never know when you'll get the response. So I feel like this is not the right approach. But what you might need is `async:false` [ * NOT THE RIGHT WAY TO DO THIS * ]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052543/how-to-fire-ajax-request-periodically

Comment: Also relevant - that condition is not what you think it is. Here is [some more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Comment: Your if statement will never be true either, `i` will never equal the array length.

Comment: @MageshKumaar  Just call ajax as async:false

Comment: @Pablo that's what I said?

Comment: If you really need the value of "i" you'll need to make a synchronous call, thinking you cannot change the api

Comment: @MageshKumaar Sorry, didn't see.

Comment: @RicardoPontual erm, not true. If you use a closure, you'd have access to the correct values from the call time.

Comment: `i` in your case will be set to last value because ajax call will be executed when for loop will already end and in javascript var in for loop don't create new scope only function does. This is standard closure in for loop, see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/387194)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you can call all requests considering their success without running an request over another:

```
var arr = [];
var users = ["brunofin", "comster404", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

var runRequests = function(userIndex) {
  if (users.length == userIndex) {
    console.log("runRequests Success", arr);
    return;
  }

  var user = users[userIndex];

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + user,
    success: function(data) {
      arr.push(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      arr.push({});
      console.error("runRequests Error", "user", arguments);
    },
    complete: function() {
      runRequests(++userIndex);
    }
  });
};

runRequests(0);
```

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yzLdyoof/)

Comment: This works but how do I make it continue even when it encounters error? (for example, I want to `push` 'blank' in the array if there's an error)

Comment: @OchiFortune code updated.

Comment: Works just as I wanted! Thank you

Comment: @OchiFortune nice, glad to help!

Comment: nice one! saved me from the edge of insanity :)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of the asynchronous nature. By the time the ajax callbacks are called, `i == user.length` is already true. But in your case you can just change:

```
if (i == users.length) {
```

to:

```
if (arr.length == users.length) {
```

This will also work nice if the callbacks are not executed in the same order as you initiated the ajax requests.

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure indise the loop and bound it with `i`

```
var arr = [];
var users = ["brunofin", "comster404", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
(function(x){
 $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + users[x],
    success: function(data) {
      arr.push(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      arr.push("blank");
    },
    complete: function() {
      if (i == users.length) {
        console.log(arr); //This seem to print even when the condition isn't true
      }
    }
  });
})(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below code:

```
var arr = [];
var users = ["brunofin", "comster404", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var currentIndex = 0;
PerformAjax(arr, users, currentIndex);

function PerformAjax(arr, users, currentIndex)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + users[currentIndex],
        success: function(data) {
            arr.push(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            arr.push("blank");
        },
        complete: function() {
            currentIndex++;
            if (currentIndex == users.length) {
                console.log(arr); //This seem to print even when the condition isn't true
            }
            else
            {
                PerformAjax(arr,users,currentIndex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain what the statement `PerformAjax(arr, users, currentIndex);` does?

Comment: as we have written a separate function to perform ajax call; we are at first set the `currentIndex =0` and call this function. Now inside that function; ajax call gets executed for current user and on `complete:` we move to next user via `currentIndex++;` and perform the same ajax for next user till the time we reach end of user array. I hope this flow is clear.

Comment: Excellent.... Works as expected. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a closure. Whenever you have something asynchronous in a loop, it is the same thing.

```
for (var i .....) {
  async(function() {
    use(i);
  }
}
```

In this pseudocode snippet, the inner function captures the storage location referenced by i. The loop runs, the i increments to its final value, and then the async callbacks start getting called, all of them looking up the exact same location (not value).

The general solution is this:

```
for (var i .....) {
  (function (i) {
    async(function() {
      use(i);
    });
  })(i);
}
```

i.e. wrap the whole contents of your loop in an self-executing function.

Here, the value of outer i gets passed into the wrapping self-executing anonymous function; this unique value's location gets captured by the async callback. In this way, each async gets its own value, determined at the moment the self-executing function is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code it's working fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var arr = [];
var users = ["brunofin", "comster404", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2","cretetion","freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + users[i],
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    arr.push(data);
  },
  error: function(data) {
    arr.push("blank");
  },
  complete: function() {

    if (i == (users.length-1)) { 
      console.log(i+'---x--'+users.length); //This seem to print even when the condition isn't true

    }
  }
});
}
</script>
```

---

Please have look below code wihout loop and asyns:false, tested working fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var arr = [];
var users = ["brunofin", "comster404", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2","cretetion","freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var i = 0;
var getUserData = function(arrUsers) {
   if(i<=arrUsers.length && arrUsers[i] != undefined){
    console.log(arrUsers[i]);
         $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + arrUsers[i][i],
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
            arr.push(data);
          },
          error: function(data) {
            arr.push("blank");
          }
        });
    i ++;
    getUserData(users);
   }else{
     console.log(arr); 
   }
}

getUserData(users);
</script>
```

Comment: How do I do this without setting `async:false`?

Answer (score -1):

you can try by calling ajax with async false as below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: remote_url,
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            remote = data;
        }
    });
```

Comment: OP said that he want asynchronous calls.

Comment: I want the process to remain asynchronous