# How can website send ajax requests periodically even when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, background-process

I am getting a twitter account's last tweet with Spring MVC. That is working fine. My purpose is to be get notified via firebase when the last tweet changes (when the new tweet comes). Firebase part is working too. Hence, I need to send ajax requests periodically to the Spring controller. When the website is open, that is fine (thanks to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5052661/4250408) but when I close the website, how can it still continues to send requests and do work if the new tweet comes?

Comment: This makes about as much sense as asking how to receive phone calls when your phone is turned off. Create a cron job in back end to write updates to firebase

Comment: yes. I realized that I dont even need php or ajax, right? I just call the "/" from spring at every period and I do the work from Java. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzIqEJkK_pM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run a cron job every 5 min